# Overlapping labels - Stacked Column Chart

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to resolve the issue with overlapping labels but with no luck ...

[image]

I have tried removing the default arrows, changing the colors etc in Callout named properties, set AllowOutSidePlotArea to true, tried to forbid some areas in NoMove etc but without luck ... I would like to have those moved left or right or even all of the values stacked on the top one below another but failing to pick the proper setup. Even more important would be a way to remove those small dashes that (it seems) connect labels to the appropriate bars. Any suggestions is more than welcome. Thank you.